# Ansible cisco_ios. Изменить настройки только тунельного интерфейса

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, cisco-ios

Я собираю информацию о интерфейсах и после этого мне в туннелях необходимо добавить команду "no cdp enable". С первой частью как-то получилось, а как теперь выбрать только туннели и внести инфу ?

```
tasks:
   - name: Gather facts (ios)
     cisco.ios.ios_facts: 
       gather_subset: min
       gather_network_resources: 
        - l3_interfaces

   - name: Store facts to host_vars
     copy:
       content: "{{ ansible_network_resources | dict2items }}"
       dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/backup/{{ inventory_hostname }}"


   - name: configure interface settings
     cisco.ios.ios_config:
       lines:
        - no cdp enable
     parents: interface {{ ansible_network_resources.l3_interfaces['name'] }} #какой нужен формат этой строки?
.
.
.
[{"key": "l3_interfaces", "value": [{"name": "Tunnel1", "ipv4": [{"address": "10.111.22.23 255.255.255.224"}]}, {"name": "Tunnel2", "ipv4": [{"address": "10.111.24.23 255.255.255.224"}]}, {"name": "FastEthernet0/0"}, {"name": "FastEthernet0/0.1", "ipv4": [{"address": "10.205.23.2 255.255.255.0"}]}, {"name": "FastEthernet0/0.2", "ipv4": [{"address": "10.205.254.197 255.255.255.252"}]}, {"name": "FastEthernet0/0.3", "ipv4": [{"address": "10.111.210.82 255.255.255.252"}]}, {"name": "FastEthernet0/1"}, {"name": "FastEthernet0/1.3", "ipv4": [{"address": "10.111.21.82 255.255.255.252"}]}, {"name": "Serial0/2/0"}, {"name": "Serial0/2/1"}]}]
```

Comment: Вопрос достаточно специфичный, если вы добавите как выглядит текущий формат и как требуется чтобы он выглядел - ответить на него будет проще

Answer (score 0):

Решение получилось такое.
Необходимо было найти нужный индекс и вставить уже его в нужную команду.

```
- name: configure interface settings
  cisco.ios.ios_config:
   lines:
    - cdp enable
   parents: interface {{ ansible_network_resources.l3_interfaces[item].name }}
 
 loop: "{{ lookup('ansible.utils.index_of', ansible_network_resources.l3_interfaces, 'regex', '^Tunnel', 'name', wantlist=True) }} "
```